# Mongoose add a "s" after the name of the model in the database?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I created a schema in mongoose and bound it to a model and specified the model's name as "user" . However, in the database it gets saved as "users". Can somebody expalin why?

```
//Schema for adding ne user
var newUser = new mongoose.Schema({
    "_id" : Number,
    "firstname":String,
    "lastname":String,
    "username":String,
    "password" : String
});
var user = mongoose.model("user" , newUser);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mongoose is trying to be smart here. 
It consider  the collection name to be a plural. like in your case it is converting "user" to "users"

You can however force it to be whatever you want:

```
var newUser = new mongoose.Schema({
    "_id" : Number,
    "firstname":String,
    "lastname":String,
    "username":String,
    "password" : String
}, { collection: 'user });
```